# Explanation of vector notation in 2D

Tags: notation, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I need some explanation on vector notation in 2D. I am reading a text on optics where they express some tangential vector T as

T = [1, tan($\theta$)]

1. I do not understand that notation, component tan($\theta$) is vector slope, but for what 1 stands for ?
2. How to find the "usual" cartesian vector notation components T = a*i + b*j from the above notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems just a matrix notation with square brackets. It is just a tuple of components.

Here are some more or less usual representations:
\begin{align}
T 
&= [1, \tan(\theta)] \\
&= (1, \tan(\theta)) \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
\tan(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}^\top \\
&= 1 i + \tan(\theta) j \\
&= 1 e_x + \tan(\theta) e_y \\
&= 1 b_1 + \tan(\theta) b_2 \\
\end{align}